# Merge Multiple Objects (es5)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I have a requirement to merge two (or Multiple) Objects as a single object. While keeping each Object name as the parent key.

```
var event = 
  { id   : '45243'
  , name : 'Cardiff locè'
  , loc  : 'Cardiff'
  }

var alert = 
  { node     : 'sdwan edge'
  , severity : 'critical'
  }
```

The output should be like this:

```
var mergedObject = 
 { event :
    { id   : '45243'
    , name : 'Cardiff loc'
    , loc  : 'Cardiff'
    }
 , alert:
    { node     : 'sdwan edge'
    , severity : 'critical'
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Sakil — That shorthand isn't valid in ES5.

Comment: depending if you want a copy of objects 'merged' or a simple link to originals objects as javascript default do.

Comment: In pre-ES6 you cannot infer a variable name from its value (and that's a good thing, imo). For a general case, you will be required to have an explicit object-to-variable-name mapping somewhere.

Comment: Won't you answering me?...

Answer (score 2):

```
mergeObject.event = event;
mergeObject.alert = alert;
```

Comment: you forget a fist line with `var mergedObject = {};`

Answer (score 1):

That's not really merging. The existing objects are unchanged. You are just creating a new object.

```
var mergedObject = {
    "event": event,
    "alert": alert
};
```

Comment: How can I make it dynamic, Because the requirement is to merge multiple Objects

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var event = {
  "id": "45243",
  "name": "Cardiff loc",
  "loc": "Cardiff"
}
var alert = {
  "node": "sdwan edge",
  "severity": "critical"
}


var mergedObject = {
  event,
  alert
};

console.log(mergedObject)
```

Comment: this not `ES5` code

Comment: How can I make it dynamic, Because the requirement is to merge multiple Objects